# win32 (fullscreen) borderless window overlapping taskbar

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-8

I'm trying to create a borderless window that overlaps the taskbar potentially in fullscreen (without using `ChangeDisplaySettings(&settings, CDS_FULLSCREEN);`) and I can't quite figure out how to do it. I have tried pretty much every possible `CreateWindowEx` style combination with no success.

The purpose of it is to be rendered on in a windowed borderless application using opengl/directx while allowing alt-tabbing out while continuing rendering in the background. This is done by many games such as wow and dota2 (`windowed fullscreen` option) as well as applications such as windows7 task manager (took two screenshots of this in a vm to prove the idea) (windows8 doesn't have this behaviour).

Task manager not focused:

[image]

Task manager focused:

[image]

This is some minimal code I'm using for easily testing some ideas I had, but none really quite did it. It only creates a borderless window with sizes of screenwidth-20 and screenheight-20.

```
#include <windows.h>

static bool quit = false;

static LRESULT CALLBACK message_handler(HWND hwnd, UINT umsg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch(umsg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            quit = true;
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, umsg, wparam, lparam);
}

int main()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HMODULE hInstance;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));
    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    wc.style            = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc      = message_handler;
    wc.cbClsExtra       = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra       = 0;
    wc.hInstance        = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon            = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hIconSm          = wc.hIcon;
    wc.hCursor          = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground    = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOWFRAME;
    wc.lpszMenuName     = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName    = "test";
    wc.cbSize           = (unsigned int)sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, "test", "test", WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_POPUP, 10, 10, (int)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)-20, (int)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)-20, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    //hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, "test", "test", WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_POPUP, 0, 0, (int)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), (int)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN), NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
    SetFocus(hwnd);

    while (!quit)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using

```
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, "test", "test", WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_POPUP, 0, 0, (int)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), (int)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN), NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

does overlap the taskbar but it has some weird behaviour when opengl renders on it (flashes/flickers the screen such as when the video mode changes. Same effects were encountered by someone [on this forum](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=9839.0) of some sort of a library that makes cross platform windows for rendering and other stuff. Someone also posted in that thread [a video (careful, loud music)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=567Fw9V3cGg) which shows exactly what I'm trying to achieve).

I have downloaded that opensource library and tried to figure out what is doing but I couldn't find anything special about the way it creates the window.

Using `g++ (Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.8.0 20121225 (experimental)` on Windows8.

Comment: I saw your attempt to edit my answer, and I appreciate what you were trying to do. The usual approach to show what finally worked is to edit it into your question.

Comment: @MarkRansom I see, thanks for letting me know that. While I was doing all that the new answer popped up though, going to play a little with the `SetWindowPlacement` idea before I make up my mind which one to use.

Comment: If you feel the need to change your selected answer I won't take it personally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`SetWindowPos` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set your window TOPMOST. When you get a message saying you lost the focus, make it non-topmost again so the other window you switched to can appear.

Comment: Mark, Can you comment on which message would say that it lost the focus? Thanks! (I just ran into this same issue.)

Comment: @bodacydo try [`WM_KILLFOCUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646282(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 9):

Raymond Chen [explained how to switch in and out of full screen mode](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100412-00/?p=14353) rather simply by changing the window style with [SetWindowLong(Ptr)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), using [SetWindowPlacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633544(v=vs.85).aspx) to resize the window, and [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make sure the frame redraws.

The Task Bar detects when a window is trying to be full screen and automatically gets out of the way.

Comment: Interesting bit about the taskbar behavior, I assumed you needed to be topmost to get on top of it.